# Cannot debug FireMonkey applications on OS X 10.7.3 with XE2 Update 4

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

### Short recap for people that came here via the internet search.

On some installations Delphi can't debug FireMonkey applications on OS X. Symptoms: Delphi starts loading the Debug desktop and then locks. Pressing Ctrl+C in the PAServer stops the PAServer and unfreezes the Delphi. The problem was observed with Delphi XE2 Update 4 and OS X 10.7.3.

Longer description is attached below.

---

I have a brand new Mac Mini (mc815z/a model - i5 2.3 GHz/2GB/500GB/Nvidia Intel HD Graphics 3000). It came with OS X Lion (10.7) which I upgraded to 10.7.3.

On my main computer (Windows 7 64-bit) runs Delphi XE2 Update 4. I've installed platform assistant from setup_paserver.zip (15.656.945 bytes). It installed Java first (Java for Mac OS X 10.7 Update 1). I'm starting PAServer via paserver.command and it seems to be working fine. PAServer says it is version 1.0.2.

Then I've set up a remote profile and it works fine (`Test Connection` reports success).

When I run (with debugging) a FireMonkey project (I tried various Sample projects and also fresh, minimal FireMonkey application), Delphi starts switching to the Debug layout and then freezes. PAServer reports:

> Process Control Server Started pid 343 exe  build Jan 15 2012
>
> sentinelFunc 345

[The number in the second line is different every time I try to debug the program.] Nothing happens then. I can kill the PAServer with Ctrl-C and that unfreezes the Delphi. Delphi then reports error:

> Debugger Assertion Failure: "obj"
>   in ..\win32src\rproxy.cpp at line 663

Package file seems fine to me:

[image: package contents]

I'm logged on locally as a user in the Admin group.

I can start the application from `/Users/primoz/Applications/Embarcadero/PAServer/scratch-dir`. No problems there. `Run without debugging` in Delphi also works. The problem only appears if I try to debug my app.

---

EDIT: This seems to be a problem with my Delphi installation. I tried the same from my notebook (also running XE2 Update 4) and it works just fine.

---

EDIT: It seems that this is related to my debug desktop. When I changed debug desktop to be the same as the edit desktop, problems disappeared.

---

EDIT: This problem only appears if I have 'Thread Status' window visible on the debug desktop. Furthermore, this is related to my Delphi installation - the other computer I tested on works fine with 'Thread Status' window visible.

Comment: The "ControlsDemo.info.plist" file name is wrong. It should be just "info.plist".

Comment: @Giel, renaming it to info.plist doesn't help.

Comment: Did you try a new FMX HD app? I just checked and I can debug such an app just fine with 10.7.3.

Comment: Yes, I did. Do you have Update 4 installed? Is your PAServer also version 1.0.2?

Comment: Yep, using update 4 and the PAServer that comes with it in the RADStudio\9.0\PAServer folder. Did you accept the default folder etc. when installing PAServer?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is installed in /Users/primoz/Applications/Embarcadero.

Comment: I have the same issue. My environment - iMac CoreI7 with Mac OS X 10.7.3, VM Ware Fusion 4.1, PAserver 1.1. VM with Win 7 x64, XE2 Upd 4. Debugging was working well with Upd 2. I skipped Upd 3.

Comment: @da-soft try removing Thread Status window from the debug desktop.

Comment: Downgrading to iOS 10.3 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problems is related to the Thread Status window. If you experience locking while debugging on OS X, remove Thread Status from the Debug desktop.

Strangely, some XE2 Update 4 installations are working quite fine with Thread Status visible, and some are not.

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click the app bundle you can choose "show package contents". Now you can browse for the executable itself (not the bundle). If you double click the executable it will run from a terminal window. With a bit of luck a helpful error message appears in the terminal window.

FWIW: my app works fine with 10.7.3 (not sure if I've tried it with PAServer after upgrading from 10.7.2)

Comment: If I double-click the app itself, its icon 'explodes' (gets larger for a moment) and that's all. It seems that the app terminates immediately.

Comment: Running app in the terminal window shows "Permission denied". I'll update my question with more details.